# Rails Style Div Conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 3.1 Trying to style the display value on a div to none if a variable is nil

I have tried the following in my view:

```
  <tr class = "level3" <%= attributes["style"] = "display: none" if product.volume3.nil? %>> 
<td><%=product.volume3%></td>
<td><%= number_to_currency (product.price3)%></td>
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: You were almost right: `<tr class="level3" style="<%= "display: none;" if product.volume3.nil? %>">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render things you know as HTML as HTML and not as strings. The way you wrote it returns an HTML-unsafe string. Since you know you are rendering HTML, put it between conditionals and render it as raw HTML:

```
<tr class="level3" <% if product.volume3.nil? %>style="display:none;"<% end %>> 
  <td><%=product.volume3%></td>
  <td><%= number_to_currency (product.price3)%></td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what has already been shown in comment by MrYoshiji, you don't need to generate the `style` attribute if it's going to have no value.  Try:

```
<tr class = "level3"<%= " style='display: none';" if product.volume3.nil? %>>
```

Comment: Using `<%=` to render strings as HTML gets you in the habit of rendering HTML-unsafe strings. I hit a few cases this way that escaped things I didn't want and now avoid it. Render HTML as raw HTML: `<% if product.volume3.nil? %>style="display: none;"<% end %>`

Comment: @ssorallen, I do not think we need to worry about that in this case.

Comment: Right you don't. Our code gives the same output, but getting in the habit of rendering HTML with `<%=` leads to code stink like `<%= var.nil? ? '&nbsp;'.html_safe : var %>`. I avoid this pattern all together.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no reason for it to be displayed if volume3 is nil, you may just want to do it like this instead:

```
<% unless product.volume.nil? %>
  <tr class="level3">
  # etc etc.
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would write a helper and use `content_tag_for` with a CSS class.

```
= content_tag_for :tr, product, class: "#{'hidden' if product.volume3.nil?}" do
  # rest of code
```

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

If you want to get fancy, add a helper:

```
def class_for(product)
  'hidden' unless product.volume3.present?
end

= content_tag_for :tr, product, class: class_for(product) do
```

Rails already has tools to solve these problems, and I would not recommend littering your views with conditions.

Finally, as others have commented, you should only render the `<tr>` if you need to.

```
= if product.volume3.nil?
  <tr> etc...
```